# ALexa API to create intents and utterances

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there any API to create intents and utterances in alexa from a third party system like "Magento".

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check [**Voice Apps**](https://voiceapps.com/) and [**Invocable**](https://www.invocable.com/)

These are 3rd party online tools to help you build and publish Alexa Skills with drag and drop facility. You can easily create intents, slots and add utterances.

Comment: Thanx @Ussama but i dont need this. i want some API to create intents in alexa through request methods of my code

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Alexa Skill Management API (SMAPI). This is official and You'll need to create a Amazon app to use it. All details can be [found here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/smapi-overview.html)

> SMAPI provides RESTful HTTP interfaces for programmatically performing Alexa skill management tasks, such as creating a new skill or updating an interaction model.

You'll can first create a Skill using the above API, then create/update intents and slots using [Interaction Model Management](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-operations.html). To do this you'll need to be comfortable with [Interaction Model Schemas](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-schema.html) and a sample Scheme can be [found here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-schema.html#sample-interaction-model-schema)

Comment: Thank u its working....but the only problem i am getting is with the access token. The access token gets expired after every 30 mins. what is the solution for this? Is there any api to create access token.?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about access token in Login with Amazon, you need to make use of `refresh_token` instead of `access_token`. How it works? See the docs here - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/access-token.html

Comment: Sorry did not get that, when i use refresh token instead of access token it shows error like "invalid authorization". Can u tell me how to use refresh token to get access toke? is there any API?

Comment: #1 comment: No, i didn't mean replacing `access_token` with `refresh_token`, you need to generate the new `access_token` and new `refresh_token` with the old `refresh_token`. Ex: say yours current values are `access_token="abc` and `refresh_token="xyz"`, then after 60(or 30) mins, your current `access_token="abc` wll be invalid. So you'll need to make a POST request to `https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token` with `refresh_token="xyz"`(see more here - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/authorize-companion-site.html#exchange).

Comment: #2 comment: This POST request will return new values say, `access_token="def"` and `refresh_token="uvw"`. Then after next 60 mins, you need to use `refresh_token="uvw"` to generate new values.

Comment: #3 comment: How to implement this? Add a `if` statement in your logic and see if amazon is sending `EXPIRED_AUTHORIZATION_CREDENTIAL` in the response, if it is sending, then make a request with current `refresh_token` to the API(docs here - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/authorize-companion-site.html#exchange), then whatever `access_token` it sends in response, use it in `request` to get the user data.

Comment: #4 comment: Did you understand?

Comment: Thank u so much ....but it didnt work....i followed your steps in postman and it shows following error. {
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed",
    "error": "invalid_client"
}